# Reading feed using JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, get, feed

I am attempting to retrieve a user's news feed using the JavaScript SDK. This works fine in the Test Console but as soon as I try it on my site it doesn't work.

```
FB.api('/me/home', 'get', function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

I understand that the alert will just return "[object]" but I'm just trying to get the API call working right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking the user for the `read_stream` permission. You can't see the user's feed without that permission. That could be the reason for the error.

Alert the actual error to make debugging easier:

```
alert( response.error );
```

Or even better, use `console.log`:

```
FB.api('/me/home', 'get', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Calling your function too early could be causing the call to fail. Try wrapping your function in the `fbAsycInit` function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.api('/me/home', 'get', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: I just checked with the access token tool and using the token generated for my app it worked fine. So I don't think it can be a permissions problem. I am asking for that permission by the way.

Comment: Change the code to alert the actual error message to make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: The problem is, I never even receive the alert. Any code I put within the FB.api function isn't being run.

Comment: This indicates that there is something else wrong with your code. Either the JS SDK hasn't been initialized (i.e. by calling the function too early or doing it on page load).

Try wrapping your code in `window.fbAsyncInit = function() { /* your function here */ };`

Comment: That's done that trick. thanks a lot, I guess it must have been called too early then.